# Print service status by span class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner with Selenium. Please help me.
I want to create monitoring status from https://status.cloud.google.com/
My goals are like this:
Apigee : service discruption
Google App Engine : Service Outage
Cloud Asset Inventory : Available

Under current conditions my output is like this:
Apigee
Google App Engine
Cloud Asset Inventory

Can I print the status from the span class?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path=r"C:\Users\rizki.abdillah\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")
# maximize with maximize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://status.cloud.google.com/")
# identify element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'service-status')))

for elm in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.service-status"):
    print(elm.text)
```

Comment: Do you mean green checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute

Example:

```
is_active = "active" in target_element.get_attribute("class")
```

To get the status use:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr>.day.col8>span")

To print the attribute (the status you need) try the following:

```
service_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr>.day.col8>span").get_attribute("class")
```

Unique row css locator: `.timeline.clearfix tbody>tr`

Unique locator for one status is (for debugging):

```
tr:nth-of-type(2)>.day.col8>span 
tr:nth-of-type(3)>.day.col8>span 
....
```

This should be enough to answer you question.

Comment: Don't forget to accept&upvote if the answer is helpful